# Level of Model instance abstraction in a View's update functions using MVP

Tags: android, mvp

I started to study MVP as I read about it is a very good pattern for developing Android apps.

I have a class (**Model**) for example:

```
public class Level {
    int difficulty;
    int enemies;

    public int getXpReward() {
        return enemies * difficulty;
    }
}
```

And I have another class (**View**) for example:

```
public class LevelView extends FrameLayout { 
    TextView xpRewardTextView;

    /*ctr and view init......codehere*/

    public updateOptionOne(Level level) {
        xpRewardTextView.setText(Integer.toString(level.getXpReward()));
    }

    public updateOptionTwo(int xpReward) {
        xpRewardTextView.setText(Integer.toString(xpReward));
    }
}
```

Should I call the **optionOne** function from my **Presenter** so **passing a whole instance of Level?**

Like:

```
myPresenter.updateView(MyDb.getLevel())
```

Or

Should I call the **optionTwo** function from my **Presenter** so only **passing the very data we need to the View, like only JAVA type attributes**

Like:

```
myPresenter.updateView(MyDb.getLevel().getXpReward())
```

So basically my question is **do Views can have Model types as arguments of their update functions?** Because I read an **MVP principle about the Views should not know anything about Models.**

Comment: Yes you are right Views shouldn't know anything about the model and option two is the best course of action

Answer (score 0):

In this case yes keep the View simple as possible.

For larger and more complex application you sometime need classes to communicate between the view and the presenter. In that case you should have a Model for the View layer and one for the data layer and convert them at the presentation layer.